# Making different screens using Processing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I have been having some issue's with using proclipsing (or processing in eclipse). I want to make it starts in one class, and draws everything in the other. Here is my code:

CLASS "Class1":

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class Class1 extends PApplet {
    public void setup() {
        size(600,600);
    }   

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        Class2 ChangeClass = new Class2();
        ChangeClass.draw();
    }
}
```

CLASS "Class2":

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class Class2 extends PApplet{

    public void draw() {
        background(100);
    }
}
```

---

And when I attempt to run the program from Class1, this appears in the console:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.background(PApplet.java:15122)
    at Class2.draw(Class2.java:6)
    at Class1.draw(Class1.java:11)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you tell me why this appears and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, you should only have 1 PApplet. It grabs control of the drawing context (like a canvas) and owns it. In the draw method, it draws everything you want on that canvas and unless you explicitly pass the canvas somewhere else, it won't be able to draw on it. The error is happening because the second PApplet class is requesting to draw on the canvas and the original PApplet doesn't expect or allow that.

I would suggest that you don't instantiate the class Class2 in every draw method, that's 60 times a second (or whatever) you'll be creating a new object. Instead, consider this approach:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class Class1 extends PApplet {
    Class2 changeClass;

    public void setup() {
        size(600,600);
        changeClass = new Class2();
    }   

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        changeClass.draw();
    }
}
```

Now, this is not enough because the changeClass draw method will not receive enough info to draw by itself. It will need that canvas.

The proper way to do what you want is probably to use 'handleDraw' or  'registerMethod' from the [documentation](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html). It seems like these are designed to let you specify another object to handle the drawing (or a library to do so).

Finally, it's probably not kosher, but you could grab the drawing context as a PGraphics object and pass it to your draw method and draw everything directly to that, but using the provided methods above is probably cleaner.

Edit: Adding a quick code example as requested.
I'm afraid I don't have Eclipse or Proclipsing any more, but hopefully this Processing example is easily ported:

```
void setup()
{
  size(800, 600, OPENGL);
  // Register the Drawer Object as the method to call "draw" on after the PApplet draw is called
  registerMethod("draw", new Drawer());

  // States set here will apply to both draw methods
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw()
{
    // This happens first...
    background(255, 255, 255);
    // More drawing if need be...              
}

public class Drawer
{ 
  void draw()
  {
    // This happens second (every draw)
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rect(0, 0, frameCount, frameCount);
    // more drawing if need be...
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean by why the error is causing and thank you for that. But I am still having trouble allowing Class2 to draw, by using 'handleDraw' or by using 'registerMethod'. If you can, please give me an example and/or the way that that they work. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Nikpie7, Edited my answer to include the code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, then you must have a `main()` method that looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    PApplet.main(new String[] {"Class1"});
}
```

In order to use another `PApplet`, you have to also call its main function:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    PApplet.main(new String[] {"Class1"});
    PApplet.main(new String[] {"Class2"});
}
```

The whole thing would look something like this:

**Class1.java**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Class1 extends PApplet {

    public void setup(){
        size(600, 600);
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(0);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        PApplet.main(new String[] {"Class1"});
        PApplet.main(new String[] {"Class2"});
    }
}
```

**Class2.java**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Class2 extends PApplet {
    public void draw(){
        background(100);
    }
}
```

You could even move the `main()` function into its own file.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the already great answers: another option could be passing a reference to the sketches' graphics so a second class can draw into:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PGraphics;


public class Class1 extends PApplet {

    Class2 changeClass = new Class2();

    public void setup() {
        size(600,600);
    }   

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        changeClass.draw(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(Class1.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

}
class Class2{

    public void draw(PGraphics g) {
        g.background(100);
    }

}
```